# Dotcover in build.cake does not exclude clases with attribute ExcludeFromCodeCoverage

Tags: dotcover

In our project we are using Cake to build our project and also I set up dotcover for code covering. I use .WithFilter("-:ExcludeFromCodeCoverage") to filter [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute in code? but it seems it does not work. Dotcover does not exclude classes with [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to exclude classes with [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute, please try to use .WithAttributeFilter("System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute").

Comment: Thank you Ekaterina